# Duplicate in the YAML file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, yaml

I want to put my page addresses in the yml file, but I have a problem with this.

```
 path:
  api.v1.0: /api/v1.0
  api.v1.0:
    register: ${path.api.v1.0}/register
    register:
      token: ${path.api.v1.0.register}/token/{token}
```

during the compilation it gets such a mistake

```
    Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserException: while parsing MappingNode
 in 'reader', line 5, column 5:
        register: ${path.api.v1.0}/register
        ^
Duplicate key: register
 in 'reader', line 39, column 1:
```

Why does it not work?

PS: Is this a good way to place addresses in yml or properties file? Is it professional?

Comment: Your example is not a valid YAML file. A key in a mapping needs to be unique, a fact that is mentioned multiple times in the documentation (e.g. in [section 3.2.1.1](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764044)).

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is good or not depends on the intended uses so I can't add much value there.  But the duplication is because your objects have duplicate keys.  You might want to consider an array as a data structure:

```
paths: 
  - 
    name: api.v1.0
    path: /api/v1.0
    paths:
      -
        name: register
        path: "${path.api.v1.0}/register"
      - 
        name: register-token
        path: "${path.api.v1.0.register}/token/{token}"
```

Comment: How I can get value @Value("${api.v1.0.register}") - dont works

Comment: You can pass `api.v1.0.register` as environment variable during JVM startup.

Comment: I want to put the value in @RequestMapping(value="$api.v1.0.register}") - dont works